# Can I run several different functions in parallel at once?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have to run several regression models for a project. The workflow looks something like this:

```
glm(y ~ variables, data=data1)
glm(y ~ variables, data=data2)
glm(y ~ variables, data=data3)
glm(y ~ variables, data=data4)
```

I then run a different model on the same data:

```
lm(z ~ other_variables, data=data1)
lm(z ~ other_variables, data=data2)
lm(z ~ other_variables, data=data3)
lm(z ~ other_variables, data=data4)
```

Running these models take something like 8 hours, so I want to parallelize this operation. I have 4 cores, so in theory, this process could be sped up quite a lot. The problem is that data1 is much larger than the rest of the datasets, which means that 3 of my cores will have to sit idle for hours until the next task can start.

Most of the parallelization methods I've come across deals with applying a single function to several arguments, but is it possible to parallelize using several different functions at once?

At first the workload should be like this:

```
Core1: glm(y ~ variables, data=data1)
Core2: glm(y ~ variables, data=data2)
Core3: glm(y ~ variables, data=data3)
Core4: glm(y ~ variables, data=data4)
```

But when cores 2-4 are have finished computing the model, I want them to start working on the next regression model, even while core 1 continues to calculate the glm model for data1:

```
Core1: glm(y ~ variables, data=data1)
Core2: lm(z ~ other_variables, data=data1)
Core3: lm(z ~ other_variables, data=data2)
Core4: lm(z ~ other_variables, data=data3)
```

Is there a model/function which would allow me to do this?

I've so far run with the parallel package and the paraLapply function, but I run into the aforementioned problems.

Comment: Have you tried using the load balancing version, `parLapplyLB()`, with a function like `foo <- function(data) { glm(y ~ variables, data = data); lm(y ~ other_variables, data = data) }`?

Comment: I did think about that, but aren't all functions from the Lapply family restricted so that they return a list that has the same length as the input? As far as I can tell that would limit the output to 4 objects when I would really want to have 8?

Comment: Or should I supply it with multiple identical data arguments?

Comment: You could return a list of length four, each element of which is a list of length 2 though. In my example from before, perhaps `foo <- function(data) { res <- list("glm" = NULL, "lm" = NULL); res[["glm"]] <- glm(y ~ variables, data = data); res[["lm"]] <- lm(y ~ other_variables, data = data); return(res) }`. Then you'd get a list of length four like you said, but each element would have the `lm()` **and** `glm()` results corresponding to that dataset

Comment: Okay, thanks for helpful input. I gather that the purpose of the "res <- list("glm" = NULL, "lm" = NULL)"-line must be to create an empty list but with the correct names?

Comment: Yeah, that's right